# WebSphere Application Server free edition

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

Is there WebSphere Application Server free edition available for non-production usage. I don't mean WebSphere Application Server Community edition, which is WAS bannered Apache Geronimo AS. If making no mistake i had seen it somewhere on IBM DW site, but can't locate any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAS Developer edition is free of charge. http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/developer/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, it is much better to use WebSphere Liberty, which can be downloaded from here - https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/ - than traditional WAS. As it is much more lightweight, easier to install and more responsive during development.